# Actionmailer - Undefined `User' - PDF Attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wicked-pdf

I am trying to attach my PDF to an email. However when I click the link I am given the following error `undefiined method 'user'` I have the following setup:

**Controller**

```
 def index
    @hospital_bookings = HospitalBooking.scoped
    hospital_booking = @hospital_bookings
    @user = User.all

    if params[:format] == "pdf"
      @hospital_bookings = @hospital_bookings.where(:day => Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "#{Date.today.strftime("%B")} Overtime Report",
               :header => {:html => {:template => 'layouts/pdf.html.erb'}}
        OvertimeMailer.overtime_pdf(hospital_booking).deliver
      end
    end
  end
```

**overtime_mailer.rb**

```
class OvertimeMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => DEFAULT_FROM

  def overtime_pdf(hospital_booking)
    @hospital_bookings = hospital_booking
    attachments["Overtime Report.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        render_to_string(:pdf => "Overtime Report",:template => 'layouts/pdf.html.erb'))
    mail(:to => hospital_booking.user.email, :subject => "Overtime Report")
  end
end
```

It the error is occurring on the following line `mail(:to => hospital_booking.user.email, :subject => "Overtime Report"`

Answer (score 0):

`hospital_booking` on this code

```
OvertimeMailer.overtime_pdf(hospital_booking).deliver
```

is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. you might want to call `HospitalBooking.scoped.first` or just `HospitalBooking.first` in your controller.

Comment: So effectively the only thing that needed changing was `HospitalBooking.scoped` to `HospitalBooking.scoped.first` although if I apply your changes this causes other errors

Comment: but that's how it should be when you code the first time.  You just have to continue on fixing errors until it works.  we've addressed the error you have in this question. you can update your question to include the other error you encounter and we'll see what we can do to help but please try to figure it our first.